# Best Practice for Unbound Caching DNS server

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound

We have an Unbound caching server that was setup by another internal team. However, there is no logging enabled. I not only want this enabled for troubleshooting internal name resolution issues, but also to feed into a SIEM, and do other traffic analysis.

My questions (and I know every environment is different)

- Is there a "sizing guide" so one can ascertain how much disk space should be allocated to the DNS caching host?
- I suppose this might be determined by the log verbosity, so with verbosity: 1 or verbosity: 3, etc..  how does this come into play?
- Is there anything else to consider other than just adding the #logfile directive to the .conf file?
- to get the unbound logs over to a syslog/SIEM, I suspect I will need to use something like rsyslog - correct?

Thanks in advance for any help or advice

Comment: This question covers a lot of tenuously-connected topics.  You might want to consider making several questions, each of which is more specific to one issue.

Answer (score 1):

DNS servers generally don't log a lot of data.  For a caching name server there should not be a lot to log.  I'll use my bind server which is split brain and serves queries from the Internet.

- bind logs 200k cover more than six months data.
- security logs 100k cover more than a month and a half.
- query logs 10M cover most of a week.  (This was left on after debugging some strange results when an upstream server was sending bad data.)

Normally, you shouldn't need to log queries, especially on a caching server.

Memory requirements will vary depending on how many different domains you cache.  However, on a modern server this is unlikely to be a concern.